# EditText on click listener

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext, ontouchlistener

Im using elcipse juno , I tried making a counter that when i click on an edit-text the counter increases by one, but its not working when i click on an edit-text the counter never change ?? is there any other way like on text change or something??

to be more clear: i want to make an average calculator so when a user enters his/her mark i want to increase a counter by one "for calculation issues" so how am i suppose to do it please help :) ??!!!

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {

    case R.id.mark1n:
        counter = counter+1;

        break;
    case R.id.mark2n:
        counter = counter+1;

        break;
    case R.id.mark3n:
        counter = counter+1;

        break;
    case R.id.mark4n:
        counter = counter+1;

        break;
    case R.id.mark5n:
        counter = counter+1;

        break;
    case R.id.mark6n:
        counter = counter+1;

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `addTextChangedListener` for `EditText`

Comment: I guess...you missed to set the listeners for the EditText 's

Comment: provide more information.....

Comment: @Abhishek I used the addTextChangedListener and implemented it with TextWatcher but the question now is how to get the editText's ids so i can use it in the switch case.

Comment: @URAndroid man its along code the problem is before using the editTExts i was using buttons when clicked it starts another activity and then after enter the value it returns to the main activity (and the counter worked) but its not efficient, so i changed the buttons to editTexts but the onclick listener does not work with an edittext (counter failure).

Comment: @JgdshSeerm I did but its not working btw thx :D

Comment: make sure you have implemented onClickListener() and ID's which you are refering in the switch case will be the same as the you have declared in the xml file .

Comment: you can implement this `Listener` to all your `EditText` so you can easily increment your counter

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the rest of th code? You might be missing the listeners like this:

```
    mark1n.setOnClickListener(this);
    mark2n.setOnClickListener(this);
    mark3n.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: if he missed this lines he will get a force close error, so yeah we need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: OMG guys i need help i just signed up here and im trying to add the code but i can figure it out lol, help please !! HAHAHAHAHA

Comment: i dont understand what you just meant

Comment: I want to post the full code but i cant do it it keeps say  have errors

Answer (score 0):

Try This Also...for `OnFocusChangeListener`

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
switch(v.getId()){
case r.id.editText1:
break;

...etc
}
}
```